# How to debug on an Android device with Air and captive runtime?

Tags: android, debugging, intellij-idea, air

I've never deployed an app before on an Android device, I've always worked on iOS devices, and it seems like you can't run/debug an app directly to the device with captive runtime, like in iOS at least.

When I click on run/debug to install the app directly to the device (I'm using IDEA) and the app gets installed, the moment the apps starts a message appears saying that I have to install Air, this didn't happen in iOS.

I wonder if I'm missing some configuration maybe.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're using Adobe Air?  What's "captive runtime"?

Comment: Simon I don't want to sound rude but are you sure you know about what I'm asking?.

Comment: No, that's why I asked.  I suspect most people on here don't since they don't develop on iOS.  Clarification will help you to get answers.

Comment: When I've created the question added the Air tag, and I also typed it explicitly on the tittle, why would you think I'm not using Air?. Captive runtime means that Air is included in the device, so you don't have to manually install it. For example, when I do a release build, the APK has Air incorporated within, however the same doesn't seem to be true when I just run/debug the app directly from the IDE.

Comment: Are you packaging AIR with your app?  You have a choice to publish your app with or without AIR included.

Comment: Yes, when I create the APK Air is included as captive runtime, there is no problem about that, what I want to know is if there is a way to run the app directly from the IDE, just like it works on iOS, without having to install Air manually, because I can't be sure if both Air versions (captive and the one users install manually) are actually identical.

Comment: Sorry, in Flash IDE, for Android, you have the option to include AIR in the publish settings.  It's a major issue so there should be a way to do the same your program.  Is this it?  https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/package-air-application-dialog.html#d284268e130

Comment: @Artemix Did you ever resolve this issue? Encountering the same problem myself.

Comment: No I never tried again, I don't remember exactly why I needed to test with captive runtime exactly.. but IIRC there was a reason to do it. AFAIK is not possible anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is certainly possible. It sounds like you aren't actually including the captive runtime (although I realise you think you are).

Unfortunately I don't use IDEA so I can't give you any specifics on that.

I use Flash Pro CC 2014 but it should be possible regardless of the IDE being used. Make sure you're using an upto date version of the AIR SDK.